# Benefit of creating index on both table in case of joining 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables Table1, Table2 with below schema.

Table1:

> (PolicyHolderKey NUMERIC(24,6),Key NUMERIC(24,6))

: rows 10000

Table2:

> (Key NUMERIC(24,6),City VARCHAR(255))

: rows 600

though original schema is complex, above is just a part of it.

Now what is benefit in terms of perfromance if i will create index on both table's column "KEY" and execute below query:

SQL:

```
SELECT table1.PolicyHolderKey,table1.Key,table2.City
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.Key=table2.Key**
```

or if I will create index on one table which have less rows and execute same above query.

Comment: Is your database mysql or sql-server? (Please remove the redundant tag).

Answer (score 2):

As a first try effort, you can try creating an index on `(Key, City)` in the second table.  Then MySQL would only have to do a full table scan of the first table, but then would be able to instantly lookup every key value and retrieve the two columns the select requests.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table2 (Key, City);
```